Compiler can't find function declaration from header
Im working on a school project focusing on a few topics from overloading to templates
It's a multifile project with 2 custom classes that contain a vector of the other ones type
Inside of the Race file with the Race class, we were instructed to write a display() function that would print out the elements of the Contestants vector contained within.
After defining it out as such in the header:
#ifndef RACE_H
#define RACE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Contestant.h"  // include class A

class Contestant;        // forward declare class A

class Race {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Contestant*> Contestants;

public:
    Race();
    Race(const std::string firstName);
    std::string getName();
    void setName(std::string racer);
    // Overloads
    bool operator==(const Race& rhs) const;
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &out, const Race& rhs);
    void display(int n);
    std::vector<Contestant*> &getContestants();
    int getNumContestants();
    void removeRace();
    void addContestant(Contestant* &con);
    void removeContesant(Contestant* &con);

};

#endif


and in the Race.cpp
#include "Race.h"
#include "Contestant.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

Race::Race()
{
}

Race::Race(const std::string firstName):name(firstName)
{
}

std::string Race::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void Race::setName(std::string racer)
{
    name=racer;
}

void Race::display(int n){
    std::cout<<"Contestants included in this race:" << "\n";
    for(int i=0; i < Contestants.size(); ++i) {                      
        std::cout << *(Contestants[i]) << " ";                      
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}

bool Race::operator==(const Race &rhs) const
{
    return name==rhs.name;
}


   
// std::vector<Contestant *> &Race::getContestants()
// {
//     return Contestants;
// }

// int Race::getNumContestants()
// {
//     return 0;
// }

// void Race::removeRace()
// {
// }

// void Race::addContestant(Contestant *&con)
// {
// }

// void Race::removeContesant(Contestant *&con)
// {
// }

// std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Race &rhs)
// {
//     out << rhs.name;
//     return out;
// }


but for some reason when I run the compiler i get back this error
 g++ -std=c++11 -c Race.cpp
Race.cpp:26:6: error: no declaration matches 'void Race::display(int)'
   26 | void Race::display(int n){
      |      ^~~~
Race.cpp:26:6: note: no functions named 'void Race::display(int)'
In file included from Race.cpp:1:
Race.h:10:7: note: 'class Race' defined here
   10 | class Race {
      |       ^~~~

Im just very confused as to what i may have done wrong

Works here

This is not a [mcve]. Something that we can copy/paste into a compiler and reproduce the issue. There is no such error in your given program as shown in my first comment above. How is Contestant defined.

Race.h includes Contestant.h (and forward declares - why?!). Does Contestant.h possibly include Race.h?  Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes

@BoP But then the error not only list that one specific member functions but others also. While OP seems to be getting the error only for one specific member function.

Why would you include Contestant and forward declare it? One or the other, probably forward declare only.

My guess is that it's some weird file caching issue. There's nothing wrong with the code that would cause only Race::display to not match something in the header, other than working with an outdated where display isn't yet declared in the header. Maybe OP just forgot to save race.h before compiling.
